# Rebol REPL Multi line if statement

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I tried to run a multi line while statement in the Rebol REPL (aka, command line),
like in http://www.rebol.com/docs/expert-intro.html

```
if size [
    print "ok"
]
```

I typed it line by line but after `if size [`, it says:

```
>> size: 0  
== 0

>> if size [
** Syntax error: missing "]" at "end-of-script"
** Near: (line 1) if size [

>>
```

Is this a problem with the REPL, the way I am typing it, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Rebol 2 REPL, this should just work. After the first line, the prompt should change into a "continuation prompt":

```
>> if size [
[    ;<cursor here>
```

In Rebol 3, the REPL currently (2013-02) does not support multi-line expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I too got very frustrated with this issue.

But I found a truly terrible work-around, namely: Pack up your code into a string and 'do it.

So for your example the way it can be entered is like this:

```
>> size: 0
== 0

>> do {if size [^/^-print "ok"^/]}
ok
>>
```

I warned you it was terrible, right?